# Having a sniff going on at the same time as the program

Tags: python, scapy, sniffing

I have a python + Scapy code that is there to sniff packets and measure their time travel.
Everything works nicely except that the `sniff()` option stop the running of the code.

So if I have a code that looks like this:

```
print "hello"
print "world"
sniff(iface="lo")
print "this will not show"
```

So because that the `sniff` is running, line 4 will not get executed.

How can I change this? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can use `multiprocessing` (or even `threading`), but having parallel processing is MUCH harder than serial.  Consider rearranging your data structures for serial, one-at-a-time operation.

Comment: I would but even if I put the "sniff" in the beginning, the code later will not be executed.

Comment: What specifically are you wanting to do while `sniff` is running?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this meets your needs, but `sniff` takes a `prn` keyword argument that is designed for printing the packets to the screen as they come in, but can also be used for processing them in real time.

http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#simplistic-arp-monitor

For example:

```
def process(pkt):
    # do stuff

sniff(iface="lo", prn=process)
```

`process` would be called once per packet received. This would perhaps allow you to do other tasks upon receiving a packet, but would still not allow you to do any general purpose background tasks.

Comment: this does not stop my problem. Since the "sniff" is also sniffing traffic from code that is not in the "def"